# Trying to scale image with pinch but doesn't work

Tags: android, image

Here is the code so far: https://github.com/Sazbak/ImageEditor

I'm doing it according to this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html
Check the "Use Touch to Perform Scaling" part.
I created a custom TransformableImageView and set it up the same way.
Even though the view catches the pinch gesture and the onDraw is called as well
no scaling happens.
What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here is a direct link to the custom ImageView class: [TransformableImageView](https://github.com/Sazbak/ImageEditor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/balazs/imageeditor/imageview/TransformableImageView.java)

Comment: Do you really execpt us to go through all your code and find the problem?

Comment: The problem is inside the TransformableImageView class probably since I overrode the functionality of that based on the tutorial I mentioned. Also the project src is only 2 java file so far.